# ASP.NET MVC 4 Paging CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to implement paging in my project, but I am getting errors when adding `.ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3)` or `.OrderByDescending(x => x.TT).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3);`:

> Error: CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagedList.IpageList<FMSApplication.Model.TTDisplayModel> to 'System.Collection.generic .list<FMSApplication.Models.TTDisplayModel>

```cs
public ActionResult DisplayTTs(int? page)
{
    var user2 = User.Identity.Name;
   
    List<tblFuelTroubleTicket> fuelttslist = db.tblFuelTroubleTickets.ToList();
    TTDisplayModel TTDisplayVM = new TTDisplayModel();

    List<TTDisplayModel> TTDisplayVMList = 
        fuelttslist.Where(x => (bool)(x.IsActive == true) 
                            && x.CreatedBy == user2   
                            && x.IsFuelFilled == false)
                   .Select(x => new TTDisplayModel
                                {
                                    TT = x.TT,
                                    SiteCode = x.SiteCode,
                                    SiteID = x.tblSite.SiteID,
                                    RequiredVisitDate = x.RequiredVisitDate,
                                    RequiredFuelFilled = x.RequiredFuelFilled,
                                    VisitName = x.tblSiteVisitType.VisitName,
                                    AreaName = x.tblArea.AreaName,
                                    ClusterOwnerName = x.tblClusterOwner.ClusterOwnerName,
                                    CPStatus = x.tblSiteCPStatu.CPStatus,
                                    IsApprovalReq = x.IsApprovalReq,
                                    NoOfVisitInADay = x.NoOfVisitInADay,
                                    NoOfVisitInAMonth = x.NoOfVisitInAMonth,
                                    ApprovalStatus = x.ApprovalStatus,
                                    IsFuelFilled = x.IsFuelFilled
                                })
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.TT)
                   .ToList();
   
    return View(TTDisplayVMList);
}
```

Model is `TTDisplayModel`:

```cs
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FMSApplication.Models 
{
    public class TTDisplayModel
    {
        public long TT { get; set; }
        public int SiteCode { get; set; }
        public long RegionCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> AreaCode { get; set; }
        public string VisitCode { get; set; }
          
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(DataFormatString
        = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> RequiredVisitDate { get; set; }    
        public Nullable<decimal> RequiredFuelFilled { get; set; }
        public string CPStatusCode { get; set; }
        public string SiteStatusCode { get; set; }
        public string InitiatorRemarks { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ClusterOwnerCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> VendorCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    
        public Nullable<bool> IsApprovalReq { get; set; }
        public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
        public string ApprovalRemarks { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    
        public Nullable<int> NoOfVisitInADay { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NoOfVisitInAMonth { get; set; }
    
        public Nullable<int> Helper { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DGMeterStatus { get; set; }
    
        public long GuardedStatus { get; set; }
    
        public Nullable<long> PersonCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> VehicleCode { get; set; }
    
        public Nullable<bool> IsFuelFilled { get; set; }
    
        public string SiteID { get; set; }
        public string VisitName { get; set; }
        public string AreaName { get; set; }
        public string ClusterOwnerName { get; set; }
        public string CPStatus { get; set; }
        public string SiteStatus { get; set; }    
    } 
}
```

Comment: When you have a domain-model as complicated as your `class TTDisplayModel` you really should start using constructors and immutable properties/fields to ensure objects are instantiated correctly...

Comment: The error message suggests you are mixing `TTDisplayModel` from two different namespaces. Might pay to fully specify the namespaces on the types so that the compiler doesn't get confused.